# Space NavBar elements such that centers are equidistant?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following NavBar set up in Bootstrap. At the moment, it aligns so that the gaps between the links and logo are all the same distance. However, as the Link Names are different sizes this means that the Logo isn't actually in the middle of the navbar and looks a bit odd. How can I align the items, such that their centers are spaced equally?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid" id="logoStripe">
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="defaultNavbar1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav links">
                <li><a href="#"><h1>About</h1></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><h1>Pre-Order</h1></a></li>
                <img src="Images/Logo.png" alt="Logo" style="width:auto; height:75px; padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:5px;">
                <li><a href="#"><h1>News</h1></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><h1>Contact Us</h1></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
.links {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    font-size: 28px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

.navbar-default{
    border:hidden;
    }

#logoStripe {
    background-color: #54534a;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sure that you will have only those four links, you can add this CSS code to your styles and it should work:

```
.links > * {
    width: 20%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

or

```
.links > img, .links > li {
    width: 20%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

This way you make sure that every item will take equal amount of space and its content will be centered.